# Tabs Rendering Order in Custom JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, tabs, rendering, jtabbedpane

Hi you all and Happy New Year from my first post of 2017! :)

### Problem explanation

I'm currently coding a custom `JTabbedPane` and all works fine, but I got an unnexpected(for me) design problem when the tabs are rendered.

The problem is that all unselected tabs renders from left to right and since the shape I customized, using `GeneralPath` class, exceeds the default tab bounds, each tab rendered overlaps part of the tab on its left. You can check it in the following image:

[image]

As you can see, selected tab overlaps any tab coming from the right, but unselected tabs, like the named "CustomPanel2" is rendered before the next tab and so on.

### Question

I saw one post talking about overriding `paintTab` method from `BasicTabbedPaneUI` class, which is the one I'm using, but I cannot realize how to do it so I would like you to show me the correct way for rendering tabs in order to obtain something like tabs in Google Chrome looks like:

[image]

Thank you in advance and have a nice day! ;)

PD: I think there's no relevant code to add. If you need it, please ask me for it.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at the source of the `paintTabArea` and `paintTab` methods in `BasicTabbedPaneUI` http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTabbedPaneUI.java?av=f#821

Comment: Thank you @explv. I've been struggling with that class, and maybe Im stuck, but I don't understand how it works exactly so, in order to do things right, Im just looking for the suitable steps to get that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally found the solution myself by overriding `paintTabArea` method from `BasicTabbedPaneUI` class.

The default code is:

```
protected void paintTabArea(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int selectedIndex) {
    int tabCount = tabPane.getTabCount();

    Rectangle iconRect = new Rectangle(),
              textRect = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle clipRect = g.getClipBounds();

    for (int i = runCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int start = tabRuns[i];
        int next = tabRuns[(i == runCount - 1)? 0 : i + 1];
        int end = (next != 0? next - 1: tabCount - 1);
        for (int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
            if (j != selectedIndex && rects[j].intersects(clipRect)) {
                paintTab(g, tabPlacement, rects, j, iconRect, textRect);
            }
        }
    }

    if (selectedIndex >= 0 && rects[selectedIndex].intersects(clipRect)) {
        paintTab(g, tabPlacement, rects, selectedIndex, iconRect, textRect);
    }

}
```

At the second `for` statement, you see the condition: 
`(int j = start; j <= end; j++)` 
In order to switch tabs rendering order, you just have to change that condition to: 
 `(int j = end; j >= start; j--)`

Answer (score 3):

What about trying to shape a tab that is not selected into a pentagon?

[image: pentagon]

[image: screenshot]

Note: This example does not test when `JTabbedPane#setTabLayoutPolicy (JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT)` or `JTabbedPane#setTabPlacement (JTabbedPane.BOTTOM)` is set:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class TabsOverlapTest {
  private JComponent makeUI() {
    Color selectedTabColor = UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.selected");
    Color tabBackgroundColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    Color tabBorderColor = Color.GRAY;
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.highlight", tabBorderColor);

    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    tabs.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    tabs.setUI(new BasicTabbedPaneUI() {
      @Override protected void paintTabBorder(
          Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int tabIndex,
          int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean isSelected) {
      }
      @Override protected void paintFocusIndicator(
          Graphics g, int tabPlacement, Rectangle[] rects, int tabIndex,
          Rectangle iconRect, Rectangle textRect, boolean isSelected) {
      }
      @Override protected void paintContentBorderTopEdge(
          Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int selectedIndex,
          int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        super.paintContentBorderTopEdge(g, tabPlacement, selectedIndex, x, y, w, h);
        Rectangle selRect = getTabBounds(selectedIndex, calcRect);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setColor(selectedTabColor);
        g2.drawLine(selRect.x - 2, y, selRect.x + selRect.width + 2, y);
        g2.dispose();
      }
      @Override protected void paintTabBackground(
          Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h,
          boolean isSelected) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int a = isSelected ? 0 : 1;

        GeneralPath shape = new GeneralPath();
        shape.moveTo(x - 3, y + h);
        shape.lineTo(x + 3, y + a);
        shape.lineTo(x + w - 3, y + a);
        shape.lineTo(x + w + 3, y + h);
        shape.closePath();
        g2.setColor(isSelected ? selectedTabColor : tabBackgroundColor);
        g2.fill(shape);

        GeneralPath border = new GeneralPath();
        if (isSelected || tabIndex == 0) {
          border.moveTo(x - 3, y + h - 1);
        } else {
          border.moveTo(x + 3, y + h - 1);
          border.lineTo(x, (y + h - 1) / 2);
        }
        border.lineTo(x + 3, y + a);
        border.lineTo(x + w - 3, y + a);
        border.lineTo(x + w + 3, y + h - 1);

        g2.setColor(tabBorderColor);
        g2.draw(border);

        g2.dispose();
      }
    });
    tabs.addTab("JTextArea",  new JScrollPane(new JTextArea()));
    tabs.addTab("JTree",      new JScrollPane(new JTree()));
    tabs.addTab("JButton",    new JButton("button"));
    tabs.addTab("JSplitPane", new JSplitPane());
    return tabs;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new TabsOverlapTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you @aterai. That could be a good solution, but my boss asked me to make that concrete shape (shown in the first image of the question), so trying to represent a shape like that could be harder to do and not so efficient, I think so. I guess it would be great to find a way by editing rendering order or something like that.